# why update aks cluster also update the node image

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-aks

When running below az aks command, it also (unexpectedly) upgrades the node image of all the nodes in all the node pools of this AKS cluster to the latest version...

```
az aks update \
  --resource-group {resource_group} \
  --subscription {subscription} \
  --name {cluster_name} \
  --load-balancer-outbound-ips {ip_entry}
```

Cannot find any AKS documentation that mentions why and how this would behave. It's expected that the command above only update the LB outbound IP but the unexpected node image upgrade which took much longer (i.e. one additional hour) to complete just a single and simple operation.

Answer (score 0):

***Update is part of Upgrade.When you upgrade your cluster, the following Kubenetes events may occur on each node:***

- Surge – Create surge node.
- Drain – Pods are being evicted from the node. Each pod has a 30-minute timeout to complete the eviction.
- **Update – Update of a node has succeeded or failed.**
- Delete – Deleted a surge node.

So when you are using `az aks update` that do **Update a managed Kubernetes cluster**,so by default its also updating the node image version to the latest in version including load balancer.

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/upgrade-cluster

Comment: If you upgrade the cluster control plane in AKS its managed from lower version to higher, default it upgrade the node pools as well to specific version to keep the version level equal to control plane. kubernetes support lower version for worker nodes to two versions than control plane
https://kubernetes.io/releases/version-skew-policy/

Comment: Thanks for the answers. In fact, we only invoke the update but not upgrade. It's understandable upgrade will update the node image to latest. However, update shouldn't make change to the node image or incur any upgrade activities (for example, we don't expect updating the phone settings to connect another wifi which brings in os upgrade...). We further checked with MSFT support and confirmed this is a bug on Azure side.

Comment: Thank you for the contating MSFT support and sharing the correect information.It will help other community members.